# Laravel 4.2 prevent query from running at the same time

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, cron, race-condition

Using laravel 4.2, I have a Cron job which runs every minute, it takes the jobs list from the database in a similar way to this:

```
$records = DB::table('jobs')->where('finished', '=', 0)->
whereBetween('created_at', [Carbon::now(),Carbon::now()->addMinutes(2)])->get();
// Process records
..
```

After finishing, it will update "finished" field to 1 .

Now since the cron job is running every minute, i need to make sure that if the cron job started before the previous one finishes, it would not run or not select the same records.

Comment: It sounds like you need a proper queue system. In an effort to simulate that, you could set some kind of flag on the file system (or in something like memcached) that is read by your cron process to see if a job is presently running to allow it to reschedule itself. Just be careful because even if you ensure these things don't run simultaneously they could run out of sync (if you care about the order in which they run at all).

Comment: @Emn1ty Order is unnecessary in my case, however i'd like to see if there is a simpler/better solution than storing all rows ids in a file

Comment: How about using transactions?

Comment: @Daenu that's a great idea, was just testing it. with lock it should work

Comment: Glad that I contributed to the solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved this issue using transaction & lockForUpdate:

```
DB::beginTransaction();
$records = DB::table('jobs')->where('finished', '=', 0)->lockForUpdate()->get();
// process
DB::commit();
```